# Game Engine: Cube is rolling instead of moving forward

Tags: game-engine, physics, rigid-body-simulation

In the Blender Game engine, I used servo control to try to get a cube to move. Instead, it rolled. Below are the settings for the servo control actuator:

[image]

And here is a picture of it rolling:

[image]

Also, the yellow cube (Character being controlled) has rigid body physics, and the ground (white) is static.

How can I stop this?

Comment: I tried locking the rotation on the -axis, and it worked. However, I eventually want the cube to be able to rotate as it goes downhill.

Comment: Oops. I just forgot to add collision bounds!

Comment: Yes, and because of the friction on the ground, it is trying to drag your cube along the ground. It is easier for the cube to roll than to be dragged along, so it roles. changing the collision bounds will make it tumble instead of roll. (with enough force)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the cube dynamic.I think it rolls cause it has rigid attributes.

Comment: I think i fixed my issue by just adding collision bounds! I had forgotten them earlier!